# change database for database queue driver in laravel v4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am working laravel 4.2 project and I configured database queue driver as third party from [DB Queue Driver](https://github.com/davelip/laravel-database-queue) but my concern is that I want to use different database for db queue driver instead of current database. I change the connection and but I don't find any solution over the internet to find the solution to change database for queue only. Guide to solve this issue

Comment: You can do this in queue.php file under config folder

Answer (score 0):

You can create new connection for your queue in your **database.php**

```
'connections' => [
        'queue' => [
            'driver'    => 'pgsql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', $host),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', $database),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', $username),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', $password),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'schema'    => 'public',
        ],
    ]
]
```

And modify the existing database driver connection in **queue.php**

```
'connections' => [
    'database' => [
        'driver'     => 'database',
        'connection' => 'queue', 
        'table'      => 'jobs',
        'queue'      => 'default',
        'expire'     => 60
]
```

Hope it help you !!

Comment: On my Laravel 4.2 this doesnt work, I get an error "No connector for [database]"